# Why does this C# Rest request only return 1 json result

Tags: c#, json, rest, linq-to-sql

I have two entries in my db table that I expect the request to return but its only returning the first.

```
dbo.Bokning
ID___PersonalId___Pris__
1  |    1       | 400 |
2  |    1       | 200 |
```

This is my service

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           UriTemplate = "/personalbokningar/{personalId}")]
public List<Bokning> getPersonalBokningar(string personalId)
        {
            using (demoDBEntities dc = new demoDBEntities())
            {
                List<Bokning> bokningar = new List<Bokning>();
                try
                {
                    int id = Int32.Parse(personalId);

                    IQueryable<Bokning> qBokningar = from bokning in dc.Bokning
                                        where bokning.PersonalId == id
                                        select bokning;

                    if (qBokningar != null)
                    {
                        foreach (Bokning b in qBokningar)
                        {
                            bokningar.Add(b);
                        }
                        return bokningar;

                    }
                    else return null;
                }
                catch
                {
                    return null;
                }

            }
        }
```

Calling /personalbokningar/1 only returns one object when it should give two.

Edit:

Ok so I updated my entries in the Db to

```
ID___PersonalId___Pris__
1  |    2       | 400 |
2  |    2       | 200 |
```

and I called /personalbokningar/2 which gave me no results, then I called /personalbokningar/1 and it gave me one result but the PersonalId was still 1.

the second row I added a bit after the first one.

Comment: Are you sure that the `PersonalId`-property is mapped to the correct column. (By default it would, just checking if you may have overridden it)

Comment: I doubt I have, I mean it is after all returning the first bokning.

Comment: That's exactly what would be returned if you have mapped the PersonalId-property to the ID column in the database

Comment: You are not showing us the View, so maybe you are not iterating over the results. Change `where bokning.PersonalId == id` to `where bokning.Pris > id` and see if that displays more than one row. If it does, the problem is what Kenneth said. If not, the problem is in your view, not this code.

Comment: The mappings are fine, just checked. Altough I added the second row in the db after i created the entity model, do I need to update the model ?

Comment: No, there's nothing to update.

Comment: Ok "IQueryable<Bokning> qBokningar = from bokning in dc.Bokning
                                        select bokning;" also only returned one row. Whats "The view" ?

Comment: "CREATE VIEW [dbo].[View]
 AS SELECT * FROM Bokning" gives me both results

Comment: By view, he means an ASP.NET MVC view. That's not the point here though, since you're using a service and not rendering it per se. If your mappings are correct, the only thing I can imagine is that you're looking at a different database. Try to update the first row and see if you can fetch the updated values (just to make sure you're looking at the same DB as your code)

Comment: @user3621898 If you put a breakpoint at `return bokningar;`, does it contain the two values?

Comment: Because of your edit, I'm inclined to think that you are looking at a different database. Could you compare the connection strings from your application and the tool you're looking at the database with?

Comment: Yep that was the problem Kenneth, my model referenced to a earlier db that I later copied.. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I redid my EF model and noticed I referenced it to the wrong database, so the rows didnt update.